# Can you access/modify parameters from a PostCommandLookupAction in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, executioncontext

Hooking all instances of a command like `cd` and would like to verify and possibly modify input.

```
$executionContext.SessionState.InvokeCommand.PostCommandLookupAction = {
    param($CommandName, $CommandLookupEventArgs)
    #Only hook cd
    if($CommandLookupEventArgs.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace" -and $CommandName -eq "cd"){
       //Do modification here
    }
}
```

Is there a variable that provides access to modify the parameters passed to cd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the `CommandScriptBlock` the args will be available inside that scriptblock e.g.:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.PostCommandLookupAction = {
    param($s,$ea) 
    if ($ea.commandname -eq 'cd') { 
        write-host "Intercpeting CD command"
        $ea.CommandScriptBlock = {Set-Location @args}
        $ea.StopSearch = $true
    } 
}
```